# How to update shiny module with reactive dataframe from another module

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

The goal of this module is create a reactive barplot that changes based on the output of a data selector module. Unfortunately the barplot does not update. It's stuck at the first variable that's selected.

I've tried creating observer functions to update the barplot, to no avail. I've also tried nesting the selector server module within the barplot module, but I get the error: Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')"

I just need some way to tell the barplot module to update whenever the data it's fed changes.

**Barplot Module:**

```
#UI

barplotUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(plotlyOutput(NS(id, "barplot"), height = "300px"))
}

#Server
#' @param data Reactive element from another module: reactive(dplyr::filter(austin_map, var == input$var)) 
barplotServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    #Data Manipulation
    bardata <- reactive({
      bar <-
        data  |>
        mutate(
          `> 50% People of Color` = if_else(`% people of color` >= 0.5, 1, 0),
          `> 50% Low Income` = if_else(`% low-income` >= 0.5, 1, 0)
        )
      
      total_av <- mean(bar$value)
      poc <- bar |> filter(`> 50% People of Color` == 1)
      poc_av <- mean(poc$value)
      lowincome <- bar |> filter(`> 50% Low Income` == 1)
      lowincome_av <- mean(lowincome$value)
      bar_to_plotly <-
        data.frame(
          y = c(total_av, poc_av, lowincome_av),
          x = c("Austin Average",
                "> 50% People of Color",
                "> 50% Low Income")
        )
      
      return(bar_to_plotly)
    })
    
    #Plotly Barplot
    output$barplot <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(
        x = bardata()$x,
        y = bardata()$y,
        color = I("#00a65a"),
        type = 'bar'
        
      ) |>
        config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
      
    })
  })
}
```

**EDIT :**
**Data Selector Module**

```
dataInput <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    pickerInput(
      NS(id, "var"),
      label = NULL,
      width = '100%',
      inline = FALSE,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                     size = 10),
      choices =list(
            "O3",
            "Ozone - CAPCOG",
            "Percentile for Ozone level in air",
            "PM2.5",
            "PM2.5 - CAPCOG",
            "Percentile for PM2.5 level in air")
    )
  )
}

dataServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    austin_map <- readRDS("./data/austin_composite.rds")
    austin_map <- as.data.frame(austin_map)
    austin_map$value <- as.numeric(austin_map$value)
    
    list(
      var = reactive(input$var),
      df = reactive(austin_map |> dplyr::filter(var == input$var))
    )
    
  })
}
```

**Simplified App**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

source("barplot.r")
source("datamod.r")


ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    dataInput("data"),
    barplotUI("barplot")
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- dataServer("data")
  variable <- data$df
  
  
  barplotServer("barplot", data = variable())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Some rows of your data and the app you want to embed this module in would be helpful to answer this.

Comment: As @TimTeaFan writes, we ned more detail from you to provide a complete answer.  However, the pronciple will be to pass the return value   from the selector module as an argument to the plot module server function.  [This page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicate-bet-modules.html) should help.

Comment: @Limey I have seen that page. It shows how to pass a simple input, but I'm trying to pass an entire reactive dataframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, passing a reactive dataset as an argument to a module server is no different to passing an argument of any other type.

Here's a MWE that illustrates the concept, passing either `mtcars` or a data frame of random values between a selection module and a display module.

The critical point is that the selection module returns the *reactive* [`data`], not the *reactive's value* [`data()`] to the main server function and, in turn, the *reactive*, not the *reactive's value* is passed as a parameter to the plot module.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Select module
selectUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    selectInput(ns("select"), "Select a dataset", c("mtcars", "random"))
}

selectServer <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            data <- reactive({
                if (input$select == "mtcars") {
                    mtcars
                } else {
                    tibble(x=runif(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rbinom(n=10, size=20, prob=0.3))
                } 
            })
            
            return(data)
        }
    )
}

# Barplot module
barplotUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    tagList(
        selectInput(ns("variable"), "Select variable:", choices=c()),
        plotOutput(ns("plot"))
    )
}

barplotServer <- function(id, plotData) {
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            ns <- NS(id)
            
            observeEvent(plotData(), {
                updateSelectInput(
                    session, 
                    "variable", 
                    choices=names(plotData()), 
                    selected=names(plotData()[1])
                )
            })
            
            output$plot <- renderPlot({
                # There's an irritating transient error as the dataset
                # changes, but handling it would
                # detract from the purpose of this answer
                plotData() %>% 
                    ggplot() + geom_bar(aes_string(x=input$variable))

            })
        }
    )
}

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectUI("select"),
    barplotUI("plot")
)

# Main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    selectedData <- selectServer("select")
    barplotServer <- barplotServer("plot", plotData=selectedData)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you. Understanding how the data transfer was defined was crucial.